# How to select particular from list item in Cypress

Tags: cypress

```
<ul class="ItemList">
  <li class="Item" data-id="2"><label><input type="checkbox" value="on"><span>bb</span><button type="button">X</button></label></li>
  <li class="Item" data-id="3"><label><input type="checkbox" value="on"><span>aaa</span><button type="button">X</button></label></li>
</ul>
```

from the above list I need to select second item and select the check box.

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I am new to Cypress. Want to click on X button based on the <span>aaa</span> element or based on row number

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Did you read the docs? *Try* anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
cy.contains('aaa')
  .parent()
  .find('input')
  .check()
```

This will search for the text of the second checkbox, then gets the parent and searches for an 'input' within that parent. And check it after all.

If you want to click the 'X' per element it's just as easy:

```js
cy.contains('aaa')
  .parent()
  .find('button')
  .click()
```

Comment: Please can you help me to click on X button based on the <span>aaa</span> element or any row

Comment: I expanded the answer with the button click. Please accept the answer (by hitting the `^` beside it) if an answer pleases you.